# preg_replace - only URL which is starting from "http" and ending by ".flv"

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an replacement which remove everything what is not between "http://" and ".flv".

Here is my code:

```
preg_replace('"http://(.*?).f;v"', '', $code);
```

but it doesn't work.
Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Also this will remove everything that starts with http:// and ends with flv and you wrote "not between". You need to escape dot before flv too (\.flv). As @Rizier123 mentioned, your delimiters are wrong. And why don't just preg_match_all to this pattern and collect matching values? You can implode them if you need them in one string.

Comment: The delimiters are fine.

Answer (score 1):

> remove everything what is not between "http://" and ".flv"

http://**example.com/path/test**.flv?param=1 --> example.com/path/test

BTW, you have a typo in `f;v`, and your delimiters may cause problems. Replace

```
preg_replace('"http://(.*?).f;v"', '', $code);
```

with

```
preg_replace('/http\:\/\/(.*?)\.flv.*/i', '$1', $code);
```

Comment: Does it work? Does it remove *everything what is not between "http://" and ".flv"*?

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the domain and path?

Comment: That's what Newester specified, not me. :-)

Comment: He said *what is NOT between* which IMHO means remove everything but keep this sort of URLs intact. But I guess you better wait for his confirmation.

Comment: I'm on the same page as you @cascaval. I've updated my answer, but let's wait for the OP to respond

Comment: @Newster Hello, was this indeed what you wanted as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

`http:\/\/(.*?).flv`

`http://www.somesite.com/ac.flv`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/tN2tG2/1